# Substracting 64bit numbers in x86 assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86

How can I substract 64 bit numbers using 386 assembler?

Comment: @starblue, I wouldn't tag this as 64bit, because technically it's 32-bit arithmetic on a 32-bit machine.  Isn't that tag somewhat misleading?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea is to use the `SBB` (sub with borrow) instruction.  For instance, if I have two numbers:

1. `edx:eax`
2. `ecx:ebx`

then this will put the difference in `edx:eax`:

```
sub eax, ebx
sbb edx, ecx
```

The idea is that you can subtract each part separately, but you need to borrow from the MSBs to the LSBs.  `SBB` does just that:

`SBB dest, src` means:

```
dest <-- dest - src - EFLAGS.CF
```

Which is convenient because:

`SUB dest, src` means:

```
dest <-- dest - src
EFLAGS.CF <-- borrow from subtraction
```